# How can I simulate samples that follow the same trend than a dataset? (R, edgeR)

Tags: r, simulation, bioinformatics, rna-seq

I'm new here and I don't know if this is the best place to ask this question, or of this is the best way to ask my question.

I am running an experiment to detect statistically significant differences in gene expression between samples from two different groups using `edgeR` in `R` environment. However, I have very little number of samples due to costs of producing them.

The data is basically a table with approximately 27,000 rows (one per gene), and 8 columns representing the data of 4 individuals, stacked as follows:

```
>head(data)
1251.1G 1251.1S 1251.2G 1251.2S 1452.1G 1452.1S 1452.2G 1452.2S
ENSOARG00000017577       3       9      14       3      23       3      23      24
ENSOARG00000020430       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0
ENSOARG00000017587       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0
ENSOARG00000025485       1       2       2      10       0       0       5       1
ENSOARG00000017595       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0
ENSOARG00000017608      71      72     154     164      41      38     100     103
```

In which the numbers represent the individual (e.g. `1251.1`) and `G` or `S` represent the sample type, and `rownames` are the names of the genes. The observations in the data frame are the number of gene counts for each gene in each sample. I am interested in detecting differences between `G` and `S` as factors.

I hypothesise that the inability to detect differences between the groups is due to mainly i) low biological variability between `G` and `S` samples, and ii) low number of samples. So I decided that I would like to see what would have happened if I had decided to keep collecting samples (not that I could, tho), and the samples followed the trends in the current data. So I would like to simulate some data, however I do not know how to do this. Could you help me with this? This is purely hypothetical (the study is already published), but I am curious about the hypothesised outcome.

The simulated data needs to accurately "mimic" the current data (to keep the differences between `G` and `S` relatively constant) while also being "different" enough to be different biological samples. I am not sure I am being clear enough and I am happy to expand if needed, but simply put I want to simulate further biological replicates while maintaining the differences between the differences between the `G` and `S` columns so instead of having 8 total samples (4 `G`s and 4 `S`s from 4 individuals), I can run a simulated analysis with, say, 16 or 20 total samples.

Can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi! To make sure I understand: you have data from 4 patients, and you would like to randomly draw patients from this little pool of patients until you have for instance 8 patients (8G and 8S=16 total samples) ? A random draw could be: patients n°1, n°1, n°1, n°2, n°2, n°3, n°3, n°4 . Is that it?

Comment: @A.FC Hi! Thanks for answering. Rather than drawing patients from this pool to increase the number of patients, I need to "simulate" new patients using the first four as guidance. So instead of being clones, they need to be similar enough in their `G` and `S` samples to simulate a bigger dataset (that we couldn't get due to budget). Which original patient the simulated ones are similar to could be random.

Comment: Honestly, I'm not sure how to proceed to simulate new G and S samples. Can we create an artificial patient by pooling together all the genes of existing patients (27,000*4) and randomly pick 27,000 genes? Or for each of the 27,000 genes, we choose one from a patient out of 4? Since the value of G and S probably depend on the gene I guess it would not make sense.

Comment: Hi @A.FC, no worries. I ended up simulating the data using negative binomial distribution centered around the row means and with some slight variability. Maybe you can tell me what you think of the approach? See Step 7 in this document: https://sebastian-qr.github.io/RNA_Seq_portfolio.html for the code.